# Relationship between classes Order-Return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have my order class created, you can make Orders and View the orders. However now I am trying to create a "Returns" page that basically allows the user to enter a return reason and then print the reason/invoice. I have the orders create form however I am not sure how to link the 2 to say **This Returns Belongs To This Order** all I can do is create a generic return that is linked to nothing. I have set up the relationship Im just not sure how to connect the return to the specific order. I know this is a basic question, I just couldn't find anything online to help me. Im a student and an explanation would be very beneficial as I need to use similar methods to this in other aspects

Here is my controller to view **MyOrders** and the **ReturnsForm**

```
namespace T_shirt_Company_v3.Controllers
{
    public class MyOrderController : Controller
    {
        TshirtStoreDB db = new TshirtStoreDB();


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of Orders made by the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="date">choose date period viewing orders</param>
        /// <param name="order">Orders being viewed</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(string date, Order order)
        {
            TshirtStoreDB db = new TshirtStoreDB();
            string currentUser = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();

            List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.MyOrdersViewModel> list = (from o in new TshirtStoreDB().Orders
                    .Where(o => o.Username == currentUser)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
                    .Select(o => new MyOrdersViewModel()
                    {
                        OrderId = o.OrderId,
                        Address = o.Address,
                        FirstName = o.FirstName,
                        LastName = o.LastName,
                        City = o.City,
                        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                        PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
                        Total = o.Total,
                        HasBeenShipped = o.HasBeenShipped,
                        PostageList = o.PostageList,
                        Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                                   select new MyOrderDetails
                                   {
                                       Colour = d.Product.Colour,
                                       Quantity = d.Quantity,
                                       Title = d.Product.Title,
                                       UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                                   }).ToList()
                    }).ToList() select o).ToList();


                if (date != null)
                {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(date) * -1);
                return View(list.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= today).ToList());
                }


            return View(list);
        }

        public ActionResult ReturnsForm()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ReturnsForm([Bind(Include = "ReturnId,OrderId,ReturnDate,Reason")] returnDetails returnDetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (returnDetails != null)
                {
                    returnDetails.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;
                }

                db.returnDetails.Add(returnDetails);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(returnDetails);
        }

    }
}
```

and my **MyOrders** view

```
@model List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.MyOrdersViewModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Orders";
}
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 0px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        border-spacing: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }   
</style>

<center>
    <h1>My Orders</h1>
    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyOrder", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <text>Orders Made </text><select id="date" name="date">
            <option value="9999">All Orders</option>
            <option value="1">In the last day</option>
            <option value="7">In the last week</option>
            <option value="30">In the last month</option>
            <option value="365">In the last year</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    }
    <table>
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                @*<td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Order Status</b> <br />@ViewBag.ShippedMessage</td>*@
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Order Status</b> <br />@(m.HasBeenShipped ? "Order has been shipped" : "Order is being processed") <br /> @ViewBag.PostageStatus</td> 
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Order Placed</b> <br />@m.OrderDate <br /> @m.PostageList</td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Dispatched to</b> <br />@m.FirstName @m.LastName</td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Delivery Address</b><br /> @m.Address <br /> @m.City <br /> @m.PostalCode <br /> </td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Total Cost</b><br /> £@m.Total</td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffe0"><b>Order Number</b><br /> @m.OrderId</td>
            </tr>

            foreach (var d in m.Details)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left; background-color:#ADD8E6;"><b>Product Name</b> @d.Title <br /><b>Colour</b> @d.Colour</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #ADD8E6"><b>Price: </b> £@d.UnitPrice</td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #ADD8E6"><b>Quantity Ordered: </b> @d.Quantity</td>
                </tr>


            }

            <tr><td>@Html.ActionLink("Return Order", "ReturnsForm")</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        }


    </table>
</center>
```

My **ReturnsCreate** View

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.returnDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReturnsForm";
}

<h2>ReturnsForm</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>returnDetails</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reason, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Classes**

```
namespace T_shirt_Company_v3.Models
{
    //[Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
    public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
        public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        //[ReadOnly(true)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 2, ErrorMessage = "Select a delivery method")]
        public Postage? PostageList { get; set; }

        public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
        //public List<CardDetails> cardDetails { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        public int ReturnId { get; set; }
        public virtual returnDetails returns { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Postage {[Display(Name = "Standard Delivery - Free")]StandardDelivery, [Display(Name = "First Class Delivery - £5")]FirstClass, [Display(Name = "24 Hour Delivery - £10")]TwentyFourHour }

    public class returnDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReturnId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Reason { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Order")]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual Order order { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Keys
In the **Return** class

```
[ForeignKey("Order")]
public int OrderId { get; set; }
public virtual Order order { get; set; }
```

In the **Order** Class

```
public int ReturnId { get; set; }
public virtual returnDetails returns { get; set; }
```

Comment: You need to pass the `ID` of an order to your `ReturnsForm` method, and your `returnDetails` model should have a property for the `OrderId`

Comment: @StephenMuecke how would I return the ID? Also I added my classes, I have the OrderId set

Comment: You have posted far too much irrelevant code here, but I will go through it and add an answer shortly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry about that, I didn't want to post too little information, feel free to edit it if it helps at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MyOrders.cshtml`view, you need to generate a link to your `ReturnsForm()` method and pass the `ID` of the order

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    ....
    @Html.ActionLink("Return Order", "ReturnsForm", new { orderID = m.OrderId })
}
```

and modify the method to

```
public ActionResult ReturnsForm(int orderID)
{
    returnDetails model = new returnDetails()
    {
        OrderId  = orderID
    };
    return View(model );
}
```

and then in your `ReturnsCreate.cshtml` view, include a hidden input for the property

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderId )
```

so is value will be bound when you post back the model.

Side note: The code above uses your data model but that is poor practice and you should be using a view model for `Returns`

Comment: Appreciate the effort in helping me! Worked like a charm, only problem is that the Order is still null even though the Returns OrderId is correct, how would I update the Order to have the correct return?
P.s. thanks for the explanation, that was very beneficial. Also Im going to use a ViewModel to display the "ReturnPrint" Which will have both the order and returns on it, the direct data model creation was only for quick testing purposes so I could understand it better @StephenMuecke

Comment: What do you mean _Order is still null_? You don't generate any controls for `Order` in the `ReturnsCreate` view and nor should you), just for `OrderId` because that's what you need to save the data. If you want the Order to display its details on the page, then you need to call the database to get it - e.g. `var order = db.Orders.Where(x => OrderId = orderId).FirstOrDefault();`)

Comment: As far as 'updating' the return in `Order` - that will be done automatically is you have the correct relationships set up. In addition to the `public virtual returnDetails returns { get; set; }` property, you need a property for the FK - e.g. `public int returnDetailsId { get; set; }`

Comment: Your comment answered me before I could ask, I don't think i set the relationship up correctly ill need to look into that, Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your comment, but I think you will need to the new `returnDetails`, get its `ID` then update the `Order` with the new `ReturnsId` value (but a bit hard to be sure without knowing your database structure and relationships)

Comment: Trying to create a 1-1 relationship between order and return, updated my classes at the bottom, is that the correct way to setup the relationship? @StephenMuecke p.s. using code first for the db

Comment: Damn, now im getting this error

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'OrderId' on type 'T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.returnDetails' is not valid. The navigation property 'Order' was not found on the dependent type 'T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.returnDetails'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Searching now for how to fix it, have you any idea? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Too hard to tell in comments. Suggest you ask a new question showing the database tables, the models and the error message